# Grub Menu Password Protection not work

Tags: debian, grub2

I want to prevent the user from modifying the Grub menu when boot(press e key to edit mode) and allow the user can choose any entry to boot.

I refer to some methods like this:
https://superuser.com/questions/488275/grub-2-password-protection-in-debian

> After setting password, both "choosing entry to boot" and "pressing e key to edit" need password.
> After setting password and add"--unrestricted" in every entry, both "choosing entry to boot" and "pressing e key to edit" don't need password.

I try this on Debian 10 and Debian 11.
What is the right way to use "--unrestricted"?

Answer (score 1):

> After setting password and add"--unrestricted" in every entry, both "choosing entry to boot" and "pressing e key to edit" don't need password.

No. If `--unrestricted` is set on an entry, only *booting* is allowed without the need to enter username and password.
Editing menu entries (<kbd>e</kbd>) and the use of the command line (<kbd>c</kbd>) is restricted to the users listed in the superusers list.

From the [GRUB manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Authentication-and-authorisation.html#Authentication-and-authorisation) (emphasis mine):

> In order to enable authentication support, the ‘superusers’ environment variable must be set to a list of usernames,
> separated by any of spaces, commas, semicolons, pipes, or ampersands. **Superusers are permitted to use the GRUB command line, edit menu entries, and execute any menu entry.
> If ‘superusers’ is set, then use of the command line and editing of menu entries are automatically restricted to superusers.**
> Setting ‘superusers’ to empty string effectively disables both access to CLI and editing of menu entries.

and furthermore

> **Other users may be allowed to execute specific menu entries** by giving a list of usernames (as above) using the --users
> option to the ‘menuentry’ command (see [menuentry](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/menuentry.html#menuentry)).
> **If the --unrestricted option is used for a menu entry, then that entry is unrestricted.** If the --users option is not used for a menu entry, then that only superusers are able to use it.

To be able to boot all entries without password, set `set superusers=...` (empty list or list of usernames plus one password entry for each user) and add the `--unrestricted` option to all menu entries.

Comment: But I add "--unrestricted" and still can press "e" to edit Grub menu on Debian 11.

Comment: This should not happen if the superusers variable is set, e.g. add `set superusers="anthony"` 
and `password anthony 123` to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`.
Make sure you have `--unrestricted` set where you want it, for example in `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` by adding
it to the `CLASS="..."` line. Run `sudo update-grub` and check if the changes are present in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Reboot.